# Android Studio layout editor moving to selected element when switching to text view

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio layout editor I will be in the Design View and have a certain element selected.  When I switch to the Text view to see the XML I would like the cursor to go to the element that I had selected. That way I don't have to search through the XML to find it. Is there a way to do this?